# Properties of $\text{gcd}$ in Integral domain

Tags: ring-theory, proof-verification

Let $R$ be an integral domain in which every pair of elements of $R$ has $\text{gcd}.$ Suppose $r\in R$ is irreducible and $r \nmid a, r \nmid b \ (a,b \in R).\ $ I have established that $a= \text{gcd} (ra,ab) \ .$

Now, if $g = \text{gcd}(r,ab),$  prove that $g$ is a unit of $R$ and $r$ is prime in $R?$

May I know if my attempt is correct? Thank you.

Let $U(R)=$ set of units of $R.$

$g|r \implies gk=r,$ for some $k \in R^* \implies$ either $g \in U(R)$ or $k \in U(R),$ since $r$ is irreducible.

$k \in U(R) \implies r|g \implies r|a,$ since $g|a.$ Contradiction.

So $g \in U(R).$

Suppose $r|ab,$ where $r \nmid a, r \nmid b.$

$\implies r = \text{c.d.}(ra,ab) \implies r|a = \text{gcd}(ra,ab)$ (Contradiction)

Comment: If you take trivial values for $a,b$ (set them to unity, for example), you'll see that the problem implies that when $r$ is irreducible, then $r$ is prime.  This is "a true fact" about GCD domains, so maybe focus on how that can be proven.

Comment: I'm not getting what the attempt is about.  In the context of $g = \gcd(r,ab)$, why would we say "since $g|a$"?  We only know $g|ab$.

Comment: But $g$ = common divisor of $ra$ and $ab$

Comment: and $a= \text{gcd}(ra,ab).$ So why is it wrong to conclude that $g|a \ ?$

Comment: Since $g|r, $ why is it wrong that $g|ra?$

Comment: Okay, I see your argument now, thanks.

Comment: Since $r$ is irreducible, the fact that $g|r$ tells us either $g$ is a unit, or $g$ is an associate of $r$.